# Update or insert in PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am migrating a Firebird database to a PostgreSQL database. I have used `update or insert` method in the Firebird database. I have found we can use `on conflict` method in PostgreSQL database. The problem is, in order to use `on conflict`, the table column must have a unique constraint otherwise it won't work. In my case, I can't use unique constraints in my table.

How can I implement an update or insert method in the PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Write your own code, and you could do this in a function written in pl/pgsql. But how do you determine what record to update if nothing is unique about the record? How do you find it?

Comment: @FrankHeikens In Firebird, `UPDATE OR INSERT` will update any matching record, or otherwise insert one record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`MERGE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-merge.html) statement, just like you can use in Firebird as an alternative to `UPDATE OR INSERT`.